# Cython: how to write extension class subclassing `Exception`

Tags: python, cython

How do I write an extension class that subclasses the builtin `Exception` class?

I tried

```
cdef extern from "Python.h" nogil:
    ctypedef class __builtin__.Exception [object PyExc_Exception]:
        pass

cdef class FUSEError(Exception):
    cdef public int errno
```

This compiles fine from `.pyx` to `.c`, but compilation of the `.c` file then fails with

```
src/llfuse/cext_linux.c:495:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyExc_Exception’
   PyExc_Exception __pyx_base;
```

Which I guess means that PyExc_Exception isn't actually the name of the
C struct for Exception - but what is it?
https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/exceptions.html#standard-exceptions
seems to clearly say it's PyExc_Exception..

Comment: This thread is somewhat old but is about the same question and may be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/iD5-UcE8TCA

Comment: @BrenBarn: No, that thread is about a regular class (`class Foo(Exception)`), not an extension class (`cdef class Foo(Exception)`)

Comment: There is some discussion of that in the thread.  I gather you need to cdef the class because you want to add that cdef attribute (and for some reason can't just make it a regular attribute)?